# Inclusion templatetag with counter

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

## What I want

Inclusion Templatetag which returns number of uses and don't break when using template inheritance. I tried to storage counter in context, but it does not work as I intended.

base.html

```
{% block body %}
  {% my_tag %}<br>
  {% my_tag %}<br>
{% endblock %}
```

page.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}
    {{ block super }}
    {% my_tag %}<br>
    {% my_tag %}<br>
{% endblock %}
```

rendered result:

```
1
2
3
4
```

## What I tried

```
@register.inclusion_tag('tagtemplate.html', takes_context=True)
def my_tag(context):
    counter = context.get('tag_counter', 1)
    ctx = {'tag_counter': counter}
    context['tag_counter'] = counter + 1
    return ctx
```

And result:

```
1
2
1
2
```

## And what worked

Added middleware which added counter to request

```
class TagCounterMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.tag_counter = 1
```

and changed template tag

```
@register.inclusion_tag('tagtemplate.html', takes_context=True)
def my_tag(context):
    request = context.get['request']
    ctx = {'tag_counter': request.tag_counter}
    request.tag_counter += 1
    return ctx
```

Thanks to @SardorbekImomaliev for his suggestion! :)

Comment: I suggest putting your counter in `request`.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Please, submit your comment as answer because it worked well :)

Comment: Submited. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest putting your counter in `request`. Something like this.

```
# This code wasn't checked
@register.inclusion_tag('tagtemplate.html', takes_context=True)
def my_tag(context):
    request = context.get('request')
    counter = getattr(request, 'tag_counter', 0)
    request.tag_counter = counter + 1
    context['request'] = request
    return context
```

Comment: You declare `request.tag_counter`, but I don't see where `request` comes from. I know this is an old post, but maybe you can still clarify this.